# Write an underscore in a listing (removing the backslash)

Tags: formatting, listings

I have the following Listing:

```
\lstset{
language=Scala,
frame=single,
numbers=left,
caption=something,
label={ls:something},
numberstyle=\color{greystyle},
rulecolor=\color{bluestyle},
xleftmargin=15pt,
captionpos=b
}

\begin{lstlisting}
val x = y.reduce(\_ + \_)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Everything works as intended except that in the actual PDF, the line comes up as

> val x = y.reduce(\_ + \_)

But I want it to come up as:

> val x = y.reduce(_ + _)

How can I do that?

Comment: Just write `_` instead of `\_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, when I was compiling, I thought the error was that I had an underscore, but it was a different error. Making me think that I need to add the backslash when I actually do not.

Anyway, solved by just using `_` instead of `\_`, thanks to @campa